# Any way to add a property to an object obtained from [array objectAtIndex:]?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, properties, nsarray

I apologize in advance if my questions seems unclear.

Effectively, I wanted to set a tag value to an array of objects using a for loop.

```
for   (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++) {

[array objectAtIndex:j].tag = j;

}
```

Is there something similar i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it:

```
int counter = 0;
for (UIView* view in array)
  view.tag = counter++;
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what is the conditional in the loop

Comment: The loop automatically enumerates the (UIView*) members in array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the objects in `array` is a subclass of `UIView`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++] {
    UIView *tmpView = (UIView *)[array objectAtIndex:j];
    tmpView.tag = j;
}
```

`objectAtIndex` returns a pointer to the object, not a new copy of the object. So anything changed  via the returned pointer will be reflected in original array object.

Comment: But since it's in a loop, wouldn't the tag property of tmpView be overwritten as the loop iterates?

Comment: At every iteration tmpView points to the object which is at index j. Is not that you want? view at index 0 get tag 0, view at 1 gets tag 1 and similar.

Comment: Ok, so since tmpview is pointing to something different each time, it is not rewriting the value of the same view each time?